# Monit: Accessing test threshold value in alert

Tags: monit

I have setup **Monit** to monitor memory usage by a process, the check will `exec` a Python script when the threshold is breached. The Python script will sent out an Slack notification.

The requirement is, I need to print the **memory usage** when the threshold is breached.

The Monit configuration file is as follows:

```
 check process testprocess with pidfile /mnt/codebase/userserver_4444.pid
    start program = "/bin/"
    as uid ubuntu and gid admin
    if memory usage > 50% for 5 cycles then exec "/usr/bin/python /opt/scripts/slacker.py <channel_name> <User> <Level>  <Message>"
```

I am getting the following slack message:

```
Alert : Host-test
 172.39.11.115 USER-MEM High-memory-for-1-cycles
```

But I want the message to be:

```
Alert : tpg-prod-user-16-115
172.31.16.115 USER-MEM 55% High-memory-for-1-cycles
```

Here `55%` is the memory consumed when the threshold is breached. 
I need to know, whether there is a way to access the usage value, and pass it as parameter to the Python script to print message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two options:

1. Monit provides an ENV var for the **full error message** at `$MONIT_DESCRIPTION` containing a string like `mem usage of 1.0% matches resource limit [mem usage>0.5%]`.
2. Monit provides an ENV var for **absolute memory usage** at `$MONIT_PROCESS_MEMORY` containing an integer like `2844`.

See [Monit documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#ENVIRONMENT) for full list of available ENV vars.

These ENV vars are only visible to child-threads, so you have to wrap your call:

```
# will create a file "/tmp/$MONIT_PROCESS_MEMORY"
[...] then exec "/usr/bin/touch /tmp/$MONIT_PROCESS_MEMORY"

# will create a file "/tmp/2844"
[...] then exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/touch /tmp/$MONIT_PROCESS_MEMORY'"

# will create a file "/tmp/py_2844"
[...] then exec "/usr/bin/python /tmp/monit1.py"
```

where `/tmp/monit1.py` is

```py
import os

with open("/tmp/py_%s" % (os.environ['MONIT_PROCESS_MEMORY']), 'w') as f:
    f.close()
```